# Sitecore 10.2 - Capture application level errors

Tags: identity-server, error-handling

If I was to capture application level errors on our instance for integration with some form of error reporting software (i.e, Rollbar) how would I go about this without a `Global.asax` `Application_Error()` method?

Is there a preferred way?

Also is it possible to do the same on the identity server?